# Symbolic functions: Input arguments must be 'double'

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to calculate the integral of the following function using `int` in MATLAB. I tried the following way, but it always shows the error `Input arguments must be 'double'`:

```
syms x
int(exp(x) .* 1000 .* square(1000 .* (x -1)))
```

or

```
syms x
int(exp(x) * 1000 * square(1000 * (x -1)), x, -1000, 1000)
```

or

```
syms x
int(exp(x) * 1000 * square(1000 * (x -1)), x, -1000.0, 1000.0)
```

My function definitions are:

```
function y = step(t)
y = (1 + sign(t))/2;
end

function y = square(t)
y = step(t + 0.5) - step(t - 0.5);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your functions to be symbolic:

```
syms square
syms step2
```

Why `step2`? Because `step` is an already defined function of a common toolbox.

---

### MWE

```
function test

syms x z
syms square
syms step2

z1 = int(exp(x) .* 1000 .* square(1000 .* (x -1)))
z2 = int(exp(x) * 1000 * square(1000 * (x -1)), x, -1000, 1000)
z3 = int(exp(x) * 1000 * square(1000 * (x -1)), x, -1000.0, 1000.0)

end

function y=step2(t)
y = (1 + sign(t))/2;
end

function y = square(t)
y = step2(t + 0.5) - step2(t - 0.5);
end
```

---

```
z1 = 500*exp(x)*(sign(1000*x - 1999/2) - sign(1000*x - 2001/2))
z2 = 1000*exp(1999/2000)*(exp(1/1000) - 1)
z3 = 1000*exp(1999/2000)*(exp(1/1000) - 1)
```